# Hibernate trying create sequence in database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using Hibernate with JPA in a primary key generated value. I already have a sequence called 'bimester_id_seq' created in database.

[sequences in pgadmin4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTaYL.png)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BIMESTER")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Bimester {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "bimesterSeq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="bimesterSeq", sequenceName = "bimester_id_seq", schema = "public", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;
}
```

Just warnning, not an error:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create sequence public.bimester_id_seq start 1 increment 1" via JDBC Statement
```

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "bimester_id_seq" already exists
```

When I specify its name Hibernate always attempt to create it rather than simply use it. Why is this happening?
My database is postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your hibernate version is higher than 5.2.7.

As per https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html , `hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings` is default to `true` for higher versions & this might be cause of the issue.

To avoid this, use

```
hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings = false
```

in your application.properties file (if there is any) so that hibernate won't attempt to create sequence for you.

Comment: The problem persists. The ids in the backup were previously created by hibernate. I didnt know if this information is important.